# Create method outside POST method is servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

Hi I have created a private method inside the servlet. 
The method will be called from the post method. My questions is, ***will it be threadsafe*** since it will be called via ajax by many many user?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    callPrivateMethod();
}

private static void callPrivateMethod(){
}
```

Comment: The code shown will be executed by multiple threads concurrently. If it is thread safe or not depends on what you will do in callPrivateMethod(). What is it you are trying to do / prevent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as callPrivateMethod() is thread safe, i.e. it does not use a class member variable, then you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, your private method won't be thread safe as `doPost` is not thread safe in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

It is static method with immutable objects as parameters in your case (no parameters) is Thread safe

Answer (score 0):

Servlets should be stateless. Hawever, if you need to use class members or any other thread-unsafe element, you always could use "synchronized" sentences.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet is instanced only once at loading. If you want to make call to callPrivateMethod() thread safe, you can put it inside a synchronized block.

```
private Object mutex = new Object();

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   synchronized (mutex){
    callPrivateMethod();
   }
}

private static void callPrivateMethod(){
}
```